# How to create instances of a class that contains object attributes

Tags: grails

I have the following classes:

```
class Team{
    String name
    boolean club
}

class Result{
    int goals1
    int goals2
}


class SingleMatch {
    Team team1
    Team team2
    Date startDate
    Result firstHalfResult
    Result secondHalfResult
    Result extraTimeResult
    Result penaltyResult
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate these classes in the BootStrap.groovy. But I don't know how instantiate the SingleMatch class.

```
Team _team1 = new Team(name: "Fiorentina",club: true) 
Team _team2 = new Team(name:"Juventus",club: true)

Result a = new Result(goals1: 1, goals2: 0) 
Result b = new Result(goals1: 0, goals2: 2) 
Result c = new Result(goals1: 1, goals2: 0) 
Result d = new Result(goals1: 5, goals2: 4)

SingleMatch match1 = new SingleMatch(team1: _team1, team2: _team2, startDate: new Date(), firstHalfResult: a, secondHalfResult: b, extraTimeResult: c, penaltyResult: d)
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Is what you've tried not working?

Comment: You'll likely get an error because the Team and Result objects haven't been saved. If you save the Team and Result objects, then you should be okay. That said, I'd probably model the data differently, but one problem at a time. :)

Comment: Thanks Gregg, it works! how would you model the data? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try To save first..

```
Team _team1 = new Team(name: "Fiorentina",club: true) 
Team _team2 = new Team(name:"Juventus",club: true)
_team1.save()

_team2 .save()


Result a = new Result(goals1: 1, goals2: 0) 
Result b = new Result(goals1: 0, goals2: 2) 
Result c = new Result(goals1: 1, goals2: 0) 
Result d = new Result(goals1: 5, goals2: 4)
a.save()

b.save()

c.save()

d.save()

SingleMatch match1 = new SingleMatch(team1: _team1, team2: _team2, startDate: new Date(), firstHalfResult: a, secondHalfResult: b, extraTimeResult: c, penaltyResult: d)

match1.save();
```